# what does the key of this.props mean

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a simple App in reactjs. i found an example in the internet which is shown below in the code. my question is regarding the following syntax:

```
{this.props.items.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
    ))}
```

what does key means

**code**:

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <ul>
    {this.props.items.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Comment: You can try to remove it and you will get a warning. For further details [see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keys** help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Its used internally to identify items uniquely when you are dealing with **lists**.

**React** uses keys to do smart rendering and searching.

Please refer https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

using key's lets dynamically create Content elements with a unique index and
when we add or remove some elements in the future or change the order of the dynamically created elements,
**React** will use the key values to keep track of each element.

Answer (score 0):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity.

[React docs - List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 0):

- A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when
  creating lists of elements.
- Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the
  elements a stable identity
- So Keys will helps React to identify which element has changed,
  removed or added.
- Thumb rule is to use 'key' inside map() function
- When children have keys, React uses the key to match children in the
  original tree with children in the subsequent tree
- Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your
  components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it
  explicitly as a prop with a different name:

  ```
  const content = posts.map((post) =>
    <Post
      key={post.id}
      id={post.id}
      title={post.title} />
  );
  ```

With the example above, the Post component can read props.id, but not props.key

Hope its cleared.